# Как вывести из JSON время, без даты?

Tags: json, swift

У меня есть такой json
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно вывести только время, без даты
Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Два варианта: если нужно загнать время в переменные или если просто вывести (код без проверок на валидность, при разбивке строки вторым способом можно конечно и регулярное выражение применить)

```
let dateStr = "2019-01-07 04:35:00"

// option 1
let formatter = DateFormatter();
formatter.dateFormat = "Y-M-d H:m:s"
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.init(abbreviation: "UTC")!
let date = formatter.date(from: dateStr)
var cal = Calendar.current;
cal.timeZone = TimeZone.init(abbreviation: "UTC")!
let comps = cal.dateComponents(Set<Calendar.Component>([.hour, .minute, .second]), from: date!)

// option 2
let parts = dateStr.components(separatedBy: " ")

NSLog("\(parts[1]) | \(String.init(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", comps.hour!, comps.minute!, comps.second!))")
```

Comment: Второй вариант вставлен в середину первого варианта. Это так и должно быть? Также `NSLog` используется неправильно, первый аргумент — это формат, а не всё выражение, и тут лучше бы уже `print` использовать.

Comment: @user28434 не понял насчет вставки, второй вариант занимает всего 1 строчку. Что касается `NSLog` против `print`, то думается здесь допустимы оба варианта с той лишь разницей, что первый вариант добавляет еще таймстемп вывода, и почему вы решили что `NSLog` должен принимать обязательно 2 аргумента, в данном случае он работает и в таком виде, можете проверить, это же реализация для Swift